# Compute $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \binom{n}{k-2} \frac{2^k}{3^{2k-1}}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-theorem

Compute $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \binom{n}{k-2} \frac{2^k}{3^{2k-1}}$$

$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \binom{n}{k-2} \frac{2^k}{3^{2k-1}}$

> $k - 2 = t , k = t + 2$

$$\sum_{t=0}^{n} \binom{n}{t} \frac{2^{t+2}}{3^{2t+1}} - \binom {n}{n} \frac{2^n}{3^{2n}}$$

Let's simplify this:

$$\sum_{t=0}^{n} \binom{n}{t} \frac{2^{t+2}}{3^{2t+1}} =  \frac{4}{3}\sum_{t=0}^{n} \binom{n}{t} \frac{2^t}{3^{2t}}$$

Now let's calculate this: $\sum_{t=0}^{n} \binom{n}{t} \frac{2^t}{3^{2t}}$

> $a = 1 , b = 2/9$

$$\sum_{t=0}^{n} \binom{n}{t} \frac{2^t}{3^{2t}} = (1+\frac{2}{9})^n$$

My final answer: $\frac{4}{3}(\frac{11}{9})^n - \frac{2^n}{3^{2n
}}$

Opinions?

Comment: You might want to explain why $k\ge1$ and $t=k-2$ yield $t\ge0$. One would expect $t\ge-1$, no?

Comment: @Did Because $t = -1$ yields zero in the sum.

Comment: @Did Apart from showing that, is everything else correct?

Comment: This supposes one has a definition of ${n\choose k}$ when $k$ is negative. Yours could be included in the question.

Comment: @Did We don't study with $k$ negative. we assume it is positive.

Comment: No. You very much assume that ${n\choose-1}$ exists since you sum terms involving ${n\choose k-2}$ starting at $k=1$. Mind you, this is not a great problem, actually one can address it rather easily, but it is better to address it.

Comment: @Did Our teacher told us that if the sum starts with negative, we just assume it starts with zero. because for $\binom{n}{-i}$ for every $i > 0$ we treat it as equals to zero.

Comment: Seems like unneeded dogma to me (why not do maths instead, one wonders).

Comment: @Did Well, I guess it is not included in our class to study "negative" subsets. Personally, I don't find any sense in that.

Comment: *Which is exactly why a definition or a convention or whatever, should be added*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $k-2=u$

$$=3\sum_{u=-1}^{n-1}\binom nu\left(\dfrac2{3^2}\right)^{u+2}=3\left(\dfrac2{3^2}\right)^2\sum_{u=0}^{n-1}\binom nu\left(\dfrac2{3^2}\right)^u$$

Now,
$$\sum_{u=0}^{n-1}\binom nu\left(\dfrac2{3^2}\right)^u=\left(1+\dfrac2{3^2}\right)^n-\binom nn\left(\dfrac2{3^2}\right)^n=?$$